# Azure Logic App user interface not logic portal

Tags: azure

The Azure logic app UI in the portal is very unpleasant to work with, confusing and painfully unstable. Is there alternative tooling to build a flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Visual Studio designer has been request on the user-voice website so many times it is the number one request.

Luckily work is now being done on the debugging, tracing and logging capabilities, it was indicated to be available within a few months. Fingers crossed!

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps